# How to track changes to a global variable on an open page?

Tags: flutter, dart

When the page opens, the global variable `CodeEmailVerif.code` is checked in my `initState` and queries are executed. But this is only when the page opens. I need to track if the value of the `CodeEmailVerif.code` variable has changed, and if the value has changed, call requests on a new one. How can I do it? Perhaps you should use the `didChangeDependencies` method, if so, could you show an example of how to use this method to track changes and call methods on change? Or there are other ways to track changes, I will be grateful if you help me solve this problem.

**main**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false);
    final ProfileCubit cubit = BlocProvider.of<ProfileCubit>(context);
    final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
        BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);

      if (CodeEmailVerif.code != null) {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
          final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
              BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);
          await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
          currentEmailCubit
              .confirmEmail(
                  code: widget.code ?? '',
                  email: currentEmailCubit.currentEmail)
              .then((value) {
            if (value) {
              cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
                final profileState = cubit.state;
                if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
                  appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
                  if (appState.isEmailVerif) {
                    _emailSuccessVerifDialog();
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });
      } else {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
          await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
          await cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
            final profileState = cubit.state;
            if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
              appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
              if (!appState.isEmailVerif) {
                _emailDialog();
              } 
            }
          });
        });
      }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

**global_variable**

```
class CodeEmailVerif {
  static String? code;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will prefer using `ValueNotifier` with listener.

```dart
final ValueNotifier<CodeEmailVerif?> myNotifier = ValueNotifier(
  CodeEmailVerif(),
);
```

I have modify the class like

```dart
class CodeEmailVerif {
  static String? code;

  CodeEmailVerif({String? value}) {
    code = value;
  }
}
```

Listening changes will be

```dart
 myNotifier.addListener(() {
      if (myNotifier.value == null) {
        print("data is null");
      } else {
        print("data is ${CodeEmailVerif.code}");
      }
    });
```

To set value will be

```dart
 myNotifier.value = CodeEmailVerif(value:"yourValue");
```

Also, this can be used on any widget with `ValueListenableBuilder` to listen the data changes.

And hope the changes are and includeunComment

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false);
    final ProfileCubit cubit = BlocProvider.of<ProfileCubit>(context);
    final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
        BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);

    myNotifier.addListener(() {
      if (CodeEmailVerif.code != null) {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
          final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
              BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);
          await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
          currentEmailCubit
              .confirmEmail(
                  code: widget.code ?? '',
                  email: currentEmailCubit.currentEmail)
              .then((value) {
            if (value) {
              cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
                final profileState = cubit.state;
                if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
                  appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
                  if (appState.isEmailVerif) {
                    _emailSuccessVerifDialog();
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });
      } else {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
          await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
          await cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
            final profileState = cubit.state;
            if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
              appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
              if (!appState.isEmailVerif) {
                _emailDialog();
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
      super.initState();
    });
  }
```

Comment: and if I have a variable changed, but how can I then call the methods again with initState ?

Comment: I need to call the methods that are in initState every time the variable changes

Comment: You can include listener inside initState in that case,

Comment: And initState is called only once when the page is opened. But if I don't close the page and the variable changes, how can I call the methods that are in initState again?

Comment: Is is just about single String changes?

Comment: Yes, I need if this line has changed, it contains a value, then call the methods that are inside initState

Comment: If this String has changed and received a value, then execute a request to the server and show a dialog. You need to constantly check for changes even when the page is open in order to execute the request at any time and show the dialog.

Comment: Test the snippet, and you can  add condition on `myNotifier.addListener`

Comment: Well, if I put this snippet in initState if initState is called once and String changes occur then initState won't work a second time, I will have to close and reopen the page.

Comment: Did you test my current snippet ? and put you logic inside listener

Comment: I will test now

Comment: Can you show me how to use it with my code please?

Comment: try putting everything from `if (CodeEmailVerif.code != null) {` inside listner

Comment: Instead of myNotifier, should I use my CodeEmailVerif.code variable?

Comment: First test with `myNotifier` while both contains single string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246855/discussion-between-max-and-yeasin-sheikh).

Comment: Updated the snippet. also make sure to change value using `myNotifier.value = CodeEmailVerif(value:"yourValue");`